# Perl LibXML encode entities

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

How do I force using of entities encoding in text nodes in XML::LibXML?

I have on toString() output

```
<test>&lt;text&gt;&amp;"&lt;/text&gt;</test>
```

and I need

```
<test>&lt;text&gt;&amp;&quot;&lt;/text&gt;</test>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `XML::Entities` to encode the string.

In this case you will have to decode the string first, otherwise you will end up with the entities that are already present being doubly-encoded.

Comment: @ikegami: True. I didn't take note of what the newly-encoded character was.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want that because those two XML snippets are 100% equivalent.

libxml doesn't needlessly use entities for '`"`' anymore than it does for '`t`' and '`.`'.